# Custom view's IBOutlet is nil

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

So I have a main `viewController` that has a stack view to which I want to add multiple instances of custom views I have created.

So my thought process was to create a custom view that inherits from `UIView`. I want the view to always be 40x40 so I created a new init to take care of this? (not sure if this is correct):

```
class QuickAddView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var iconLabel: UILabel!

    var task: Task = Task()

    public init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))

        configureView()
    }

    private func configureView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
        self.backgroundColor = task.color

        configureViewElements()
    }

    private func configureViewElements() {
        configureIconLabel()
    }

    private func configureIconLabel() {
        // CRASH: - iconLabel is nil here
        self.iconLabel.text = task.icon
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

I then have a QuickAddView nib that sets its custom class to QuickAddView.swift

Lastly, I create the custom views in my `viewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    configureViewElements()
}

private func configureViewElements() {
    configureQuickAddStackView()
}

private func configureQuickAddStackView() {
    let quickAddView = QuickAddView(task: Task(name: "Go to the store", icon: "", color: .purple))

    quickAddStackView.addArrangedSubview(quickAddView)
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my `iconLabel` is `nil` when I try to set up my `QuickAddView`. I also don't know if I'm doing this process of creating a custom view correct.

Comment: Is the IBOutlet connected to an element in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are connecting the IBOutlet from xibFile you have to use

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    configureView()
}
```

Also in your class you have to instantiate it with

```
if let quickAddView  = Bundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("QuickAddView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? QuickAddView {
 quickAddView.task = task
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're creating a custom view in code, but using an IBOutlet for the iconLabel. An IBOutlet is for something you've built in Interface Builder, not in code. If you want to create the QuickAddView in code, you need to also create the iconLabel in code, in the QuickAddView class. You need to make these modifications:

```
weak var iconLabel: UILabel?

private func configureIconLabel() {
    iconLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect())
    if let iconLabel = iconLabel {
        iconLabel.text = task.icon
        addSubview(iconLabel)
    }
}
```

Note that I passed in a zeroed out CGRect, but you'll want to use whatever you want the UILabels origin and size to be, or use autolayout to configure where the iconLabel is displayed.

Comment: So you can't have a custom view that also has IBOutlets in it? Or you can have it but the custom view needs to be initialized using the nib instead of `let quickView = QuickView()`? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: IBOutlets are strictly for working with Interface Builder. You're telling the compiler, "this object comes from a xib file" and you need to connect the IBOutlet to the view in Interface Builder for it to work. If you want to use Interface Builder, you can add your QuickView to the ViewController's xib file/storyboard scene, add a UILabel to it, and then you *must* wire up the outlets. If you're uncomfortable with Interface Builder, you just just omit the IBOutlet keyword and do everything in code, as shown above.

Comment: this answer is clearly incorrect. xib files can be mixed with programatically instantiation.